# Removing turbolinks breaks Actioncable chat room

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to get rid of Turbolinks for now, it messes a bit my JS.

Though it kind of breaks my chatroom coffee script code.

(I have very little knowledge in JS, even less coffee)

here is my coffee :

```
App.conversationsdevis = App.cable.subscriptions.create "ConversationsdevisChannel",
  connected: ->
    # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

  disconnected: ->
    # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

  received: (data) ->
    $('#cellmessagesde'+data.cellid).append '<div class="'+data.auteur+'">'+'<span>'+data.message+'</span>'+'</div>'

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  submit_message()

submit_message = () ->
  $('.sendmessageinputtext').on 'keydown', (event) ->
    if event.keyCode is 13
      $('input').click()
      event.target.value = ""
      event.preventDefault()
```

I think the chat message is injected only because of this bit `$(document).on 'turbolinks:load'` Is there a way to inject with another Coffee condition than Turbolinks load ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'turbolinks:load'` is a turbolinks event that is fired by turbolinks when the document is ready on the initial page load or when turbolinks has finished replacing the document contents.

What you want instead is to use the [jQuery `ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) function which guarentees that the document is fully parsed and ready to be manipulated.

```
$.ready ->
  submit_message()
```

Comment: Many thanks. Not sure why this tutorial was relying on anything Turbolinks related. Your solution is much simpler.

Comment: One issue is that this will only work on the initial page load if you are using turbolinks.

Comment: oh thanks. In case I use Turbolinks again I will reinstate